# Push Notification not working in IOS but working fine in Android

Tags: react-native

Did all initial setups, upload Auth key in firebase console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J811.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all mention your error if there is no error then run the app and check in xCode debugger you will definitely find the error regarding the push notifications.
But here is the checklist you have double check either you have configured or not

> Install `react-native-push-notification-ios`

> configure push notifications in ios files AppDalegate.m & AppDalegate.h

> Generate the APNS from the apple developer account and upload in firebase console.

> Add the capabilities in xcode `Push Notifications` & `Remote messaging`, make sure to check remote fetch

> Add `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` type "Boolean" value "NO" in
> your info.plist:

> Add permissions in `Podfile`

Comment: 1.Add auth key in firebase console for ios, 2. Add capabilities, 3. Add firebaseproxyenable flag to to NO----- these steps are done still not able to receive notification for ios

Comment: try adding APNS instead of auth key

Comment: Thanks brother for helping me out! By adding APNs instead of authkey it works.

Comment: <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>